# MacBook Pro periodically turn on external Samsung monitor in sleep mode

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake

My 13-inch 2020 MacBook Pro periodically turns on the external 27" Samsung S27A600UUI (connected by USB-C) while in sleep mode.  It looks like the Samsung goes to sleep, but periodically wakes up and search the connected sources. This leads to flashes of the monitor screen at night, which prevents me from falling asleep normally.

How can I stop this behavior?

Comment: Have you tried turning the monitor off?

Comment: Yes, its fix it. But this is an inconvenient solution. First, you need to use the mouse pointer to switch to sleep mode on the MacBook (lid isn't work with external monitor for MacBook sleep), then find the monitor menu arrow buttons and turn it off after a few moves through the display menu (there is no separate shutdown button on monitor).

Comment: When you close the lid, does it put the mac to sleep?

Comment: @Allan no, continue working.

Comment: Did you change any of the sleep settings?